# How can I insert an image in a UILabel, or make it look like I did?

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel

I am writing a geometry based app.  At one point in the app, there will be a UITableView with some custom cells.  These cells contain UILabels.  Amid the text of some these labels, I want to insert symbols that look these two triangles: [image]
<sub>(source: [wiley.com](https://media.wiley.com/Lux/73/258473.image0.jpg))</sub>

However, since I cannot find these symbols in any Apple fonts, is there a way to insert an image into the string in place of a symbol?

Here is a (***very***) rough idea of what I'm going for (the actual table will not be static):

[image: image2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I get what you're trying to do. The key, I think, is to just keep adding controls to your cell, calculating the width as you go along.

First, I'd suggest a data structure to hold your cell contents. A simple array will do the job. I generally do this stuff as an ivar:

```
@interface LabelWithImagesViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *_cells;
}
@end
```

Then fill this array with the text and images you want. I'm doing a single row, but you can repeat for every row you need.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _cells = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [_cells addObject:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"triangle.png"],
                       @"CAT",
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"semiequal.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"triangle.png"],
                       @"DOG",
                       @"  If",
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"triangle1.png"],
                       @"then",
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"triangle2.png"],
                       nil]];
}
```

And then, you need to create your cell:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return _cells.count;
}

#define kEquationTag 100
#define kCellHeight 44

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"equationCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UIView *equationContainer;

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        // if we don't have a cell create it, including the frame to hold our custom stuff

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        equationContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.contentView.bounds];
        equationContainer.tag = kEquationTag;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:equationContainer];
    }
    else
    {
        // if we are dequeing one that already exists, let's get rid of the old custom stuff

        equationContainer = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:kEquationTag];
        for (UIView *view in equationContainer.subviews)
        {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    NSArray *cellContents = [_cells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSUInteger x = 0;
    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];

    for (NSObject *obj in cellContents)
    {
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
        {
            NSString *text = (NSString *)obj;
            CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:font];
            UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, (kCellHeight - size.height)/2.0, size.width, size.height)];
            label.text = text;
            label.font = font;
            [equationContainer addSubview:label];
            x += size.width;
        } 
        else if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]])
        {
            UIImage *image = (UIImage *)obj;
            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, (kCellHeight - image.size.height) / 2.0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
            imageView.image = image;
            [equationContainer addSubview:imageView];
            x += image.size.width;
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

This yields:

[image]

Comment: Awesome! That's exactly the answer I was looking for.  Just one issue, the images I imported are way too big.  What size did you make your images?

Answer (score 2):

1. Make a UILabel and use instances of that UILabel for each letter.
2. Use some geometry logic about the rect of the image view to place the letters regardless of size...such as

   ```
       UILabel *aLetterLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 35)];
       aLetterLabel.text = @"A";

       //centered top
       aLetterLabel.frame = CGRectMake((shapeImage.frame.origin.x +  (shapeImage.frame.size.width/2)), shapeImage.frame.origin.y, 35, 35);

       //centered
       aLetterLabel.frame = CGRectMake((shapeImage.frame.origin.x + (shapeImage.frame.size.width/2)), (shapeImage.frame.origin.y + (shapeImage.frame.size.height/2)), 35, 35);

       //cenetered bottom
       aLetterLabel.frame = CGRectMake((shapeImage.frame.origin.x + (shapeImage.frame.size.width/2)), (shapeImage.frame.origin.y+(shapeImage.frame.size.height-35)), 35, 35);

       //left center align
       aLetterLabel.frame = CGRectMake(shapeImage.frame.origin.x, (shapeImage.frame.origin.y + (shapeImage.frame.size.height/2)), 35, 35);
   ```

Wrote these up really fast as a proof of concept...feel free to revise, etc.

Comment: Is there an alternative to creating so many UILabels?  That seems like it will be incredibly inefficient, especially in a UITableViewCell.

Comment: If you really want to have them in a Table View, I would say you need to make images with the letters pre rendered in for those shapes...

Comment: If you could somehow work with these outside of a table view, a UILabel is a very lightweight UIKit element from what I understand, so I would't worry about it.  My only fear is the tableview dequeueing cells would cause lots of problems hear, especially with different shapes and label configs

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own font with the exact symbols you need. Try this:
http://glyphdesigner.71squared.com

Comment: This looks great!  If I could set two answers as correct I would pick this one as well.  If it wasn't for the price tag this would definitely be my preferred option.

Comment: 50% off at the moment!

Comment: Actually, I take that back... Glyph Designer is for bitmap fonts, i.e. bitmap games, like a sprite sheet. They are incompatible with native iOS text components and cannot be loaded in as fonts!

Comment: I managed to get it to work with a trial version of Glyphs: http://www.glyphsapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert an image in a UILabel.
But you can add a UIImageView in the custom cells of your UITableView and then put a UIImage inside.

Comment: Yeah I was pretty sure that that would be the answer. But how can I wrap my text around the inserted image?

Comment: @Garrett If you want text to wrap around images, you might want to investigate shifting to a UIWebView, where you create the HTML programmatically.

Comment: Yes, I think it's the better way to do that.

Comment: @Garrett I'm sure there are better examples out there, but here is a simple example of how you fill a UIWebView with text and images: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247777/embedding-image-and-uilable-in-uiwebview/11248285#11248285. You'll have to design your own HTML string, but hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Another option worth looking into would be to include some font that already have the symbols into your bundle.

Comment: @RobertRyan I probably should have explained better, this image is just an example.  My image will be provided in the app; it won't need to be retrieved from a server.

Comment: @Alladinian I tried that but as I said I can't find that symbol in any fonts

Comment: @Garrett You said _Apple_ fonts... I'm talking about any font that may do the job. I think there are numerous fonts that contain trigonometric/mathematical symbols available.

Comment: @Alladinian Where would I find other fonts, and how would I import them into my app?

Comment: @Garret A good source for fonts: http://www.dafont.com | [How to add a custom font](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351264/how-to-use-custom-font-in-ios-apps)

Comment: @Garrett When you use a UIWebView, you don't need to retrieve the HTML from the web. If you look at the sample I provided, you can see how you can make your own HTML on the fly. It does have to retrieved from the web, nor even look like a web page. Lots of apps that have views with complex combinations of text, different text styles, images, etc. are using UIWebViews.

Comment: @RobertRyan Ok then, one last question: Is this a practical solution when the web view will be embedded in a tableView cell?

Comment: @Garrett ah, probably not. (embedding a control that uses pan gestures in another that uses pan gestures is a hassle.) I didn't notice we were talking about tableview cells. But then again, a tableview cell is typically small enough that you probably don't have to engage in a lot of "wrapping text around the image". I guess we'd have to see an example of what the table cell would look like and what wrapping you'd need to have take place.

Comment: @RobertRyan I updated my question with an example of what it might look like

Comment: @Garrett by embedding webview - only problem could be - that it will load with a little delay - and it is more noticable, when webview content uses images. Dont worry about gestures - you can set webview frame as big as its content, and it wont scroll. Good luck!